# Largest eigenvalues (and corresponding eigenvectors) in ArrayFire

Tags: c++, arrayfire

Given a square matrix `A`, I need to obtain a diagonal matrix `D` that contains `A`'s 5 largest magnitude eigenvalues and a matrix `V` whose columns are the corresponding eigenvectors. In Matlab the code is `[V,D] = eigs(A,5)`. Is there a similar function in ArrayFire C++?

In ArrayFire I use `af::eigen(Values,Vectors,A)`. What is the order of elements in `Values`? In one test I had the elements of `Values` sorted in the order of increasing magnitude, however in the other case `Values` was sorted in the order of decreasing magnitude. Essentially, I need to extract 5 eigenvectors that correspond to the largest magnitude eigenvalues. Do I have to use the `sort` function to achieve this?

**UPDATE**
Here's a simple example:

```
// first example
float a[]={1, 2, 5, -2, 1, -5, 3, -2, 1};
array b(3,3,a);
array evalues, evectors;
af::eigen(evalues, evectors, b);
print(evalues);     //`evalues` are not in order   

// second example
float a2[]={1, -3, 3, 3, -5, 3, 6, -6, 4};
array b2(3,3,a2);
array evalues2, evectors2;
af::eigen(evalues2, evectors2, b2);
print(evalues2);     //`evalues2` are in the decreasing order
```

Comment: `eigen(values, vectors, a)` returns `values` as a diagonal matrix whose diagonal elements are in order of `decreasing` magnitude. Can you point out an example where the values are coming out in increasing order ?

Comment: @Pavan I get the correct decreasing order in `values` for a 5x5 test matrix. However, for my 945 by 945 array `A` (which is a result of some computation), elements in `values` are returned in the increasing order. I can't really list that matrix here since it's too big and is a result of prior computations.

Comment: I don't think this is the best avenue to discuss this. Can you email support@accelereyes.com with a the problem case so that we can have a look at it ?

Comment: Thanks, I emailed the support.

Comment: @Pavan I added a simple example.